# Windows 10 search prompting "This is taking too long to load"

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-search

When searching using the search functionality embedded in the start menu of Windows 10 (when clicking the Windows icon in the left bottom), a screen is displayed saying "This is taking too long to load". On the bottom right, a string looking like a version number is displayed as well (see screenshot). This looks quite "off" and doesn't seem to come from Windows.

Edit: seems to only occur until "refresh" is clicked, and after every reboot.

Anyone having any idea?

Edit: **after updating Windows**, **it does not seem to occur anymore** (rebooted a few times to check). Seems solved. I will update this if it reoccurs.

Edit: Each time a new update is available, the problem reoccurs until the update is completed.

[image]

Comment: That certainly doesn't look legitimate. Try running a virus scan.

Comment: This does not occur on any of my Windows 10 machines. Do a full scan with Windows Defender and look for strange software you may have installed.

Comment: Currently performing a full scan with Kaspersky. After that I'll perform a Windows Defender scan. I can't think of any strange software i've downloaded recently.

Comment: had the same issue, seems really not windows design and therefor like a virus, did a scan and got nothing. just updated my windows and restarted. now its gone...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and in my case running `dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` from elevated command prompt solved the issue.

I saw the problem first time after installation of update `KB4549951`.
My OS is `Windows Pro 10 1909`.

Before running `dism.exe` I had tried other things such as rebuilding Windows search cache, adjusting `Windows Search` service startup parameters and running `scf.exe /scannow` but those did not help in my case.

Answer (score 1):

After updating Windows, it appears to be gone.  Others reported this as well.

Comment: Not resolved for me. Currently using Windows 10 Edu, Version 1909, Build 18363.815